# Treating Identifiers as data in Scala

Tags: scala

```
case class Var(x: Int,y:Int)
def compare(v:Var,compare:String): Boolean = {
        v.x compare v.y //--NeedHelp
}
def getComp(v:Var,compName:String):Int={
        v.compName //--NeedHelp
}
val v = Var(2,3)
assert(true == compare(v,"<"))
assert(false == compare(v,"=="))
assert(false == compare(v,">"))
assert(2==getComp(v,"x"))
assert(3==getComp(v,"y"))
```

there are two //--NeedHelp statements, how can I go and write it so that it executes as expected. What I am trying to do, what it is called in Programming world? So that I can Google myself also and know more about it.

Comment: You need a "match expression" to match "<" to the corresponding operation, "==" to the corresponding operation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think there are two questions here really:

**Firstly, getting the code working:**

For a very simple, but not very extensible or robust implementation, you can "pattern match" on the Strings to decide what to do:

```
def compare(v:Var,compare:String): Boolean = {
   compare match {
       case op if op == "<" => v.x < v.y
       case op if op == ">" => v.x > v.y
       case _ => false // not very robust, anything could be passed in.
   }
}
```

*Side Note*: It is worth considering how to prevent the user from passing in unexpected values - for example, if the function took a trait of type `Operator` instead of just taking the String value, then the compiler would prevent invalid values from being passed in.

```
def getComp(v:Var,compName:String):Int={
  compName match {
    case name if name == "x" => v.x
    case name if name == "y" => v.y
    case _ => 0 // not very robust...
  }
}
```

Both of the above statements could easily be implemented using an if statement either, e.g.

```
def getComp(v:Var,compName:String):Int={
  if (compName == "x") 
    v.x
  else if (compName == "y")
    v.y
  else
    0 // again, not very robust.
}
```

A more advanced implementation of a similar pattern might make use of some of Scala's object oriented features to create different expression types and use parsers to parse a string of text, convert the text to expressions and then evaluate the expressions.

**Secondly**, in response to *"..what is this called in the Programming World?.."*

I think this covers a number of areas. It covers an interpreter, because a lot of what you are writing here is basically an interpreter, i.e. you are passing a string that represents a comparison operation and supplying data in the form to be evaluated in the context of that operation. It could also be referred to as a simple DSL (Domain Specific Language).

Also, just a personal recommendation but I believe, if I recall correctly, the [Coursera Scala Course](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-005) which was run by Martin Odersky, covered off a very simple Expression evaluation example in one of the videos (I think perhaps it is week 4). As I recall, it was a very simple one, but it shows at least at a high level how this kind of approach could be implemented in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, what you're looking for is [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)).

You can also find more information online on [reflection in Scala](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html). As far as I know Scala operators are methods, which would maybe let you use reflection to find them, but I haven't tried it myself.